# How to set datetime format in MySQL INTO OUTFILE command?

Tags: mysql, csv, extract

Is there a way to explicitly set formatting for DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP type columns in MySQL INTO OUTFILE command?

```
select * from orders LIMIT 100
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '
';
```

Maybe in shell or command itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here is that the first part of the query, the [select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) is pretty much a full featured standard select. So instead of `select *` youo could have

```
SELECT col1, col2, date_format(date_col, 'someformat') ...
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '
';
```

And produce output in the format of your choice. DATE_FORMAT reference here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format